# ViewPager MVVM, DataBinding Android

Tags: java, android, mvvm

Please help, I have viewpager with fragments, databinding into viewmodel. Where I need use setCurrentItem and add functions of viewpager's adapter (view or viewmodel-databinding)? Is it necessary to create viewmodel for every viewpager's item?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

So I created ObservableField for list and curentItem (int)
http://prntscr.com/fi4nl9
http://prntscr.com/fi4o2x

But I think there is some problem with newsList, I don`t know how is valid attach data to adapter. Now I am using only replace all data, but loading function only append news data (lazy loading)